# SQL - JOIN SELECT TOP 1 with subquery returns NULL

Tags: sql-server

I need to get TOP 1 row from a table so I used subquery when joining it. However, TOP 1 returns null value but if I remove TOP 1, it works. I need to only get one top result if by any chance the table will contain multiple rows with same primary key value.

```
SELECT Sem_ID AS SeminarId

FROM t_Seminar sem

JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 rhb.SeminarId AS SeminarId
    FROM WinClient.ReportBrief rhb
) rh
ON Sem_ID = rh.SeminarId
WHERE sem.Sem_ID = @SeminarId
GROUP BY Sem_ID
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: put where clause " SELECT TOP 1 rhb.SeminarId AS SeminarId
    FROM WinClient.ReportBrief rhb where rhb.SeminarId is not null"

Comment: You don't have an `ORDER BY`; you're effective saying "the first random row you find". It also seems like you want `APPLY` here too, not a lateral `JOIN`. At the moment a row will be only be display if by *chance* the "Top" row has a value for `SeminarId` that matches `@SeminarId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you only return the value of `SeminarId` from `ReportBrief`, and that has to have the value of `@SeminarId`, (due to the clauses `ON Sem_ID = rh.SeminarId` and `sem.Sem_ID = @SeminarId`) it seems like an `EXISTS` would be far better here:

```
SELECT TOP 1 S.Sem_ID AS SeminarId
FROM t_Seminar S
WHERE S.Sem_ID = @SeminarId
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM WinClient.ReportBrief RB
              WHERE S.Sem_ID = RB.SeminarId);
```

I also changed the `TOP 1` in the outer query. It seems pointless to have a `GROUP BY` with no aggregation, and as there can only be 1 value, then a `TOP 1` works fine, and is less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use top in the outer query

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sem_ID AS SeminarId
FROM t_Seminar sem
JOIN
(
    SELECT  rhb.SeminarId AS SeminarId
    FROM WinClient.ReportBrief rhb
) rh
ON Sem_ID = rh.SeminarId
WHERE sem.Sem_ID = @SeminarId
and isnull(Sem_ID,'')<>''
GROUP BY Sem_ID
```